# React Native fetch() response is different after updating app

Tags: react-native

I am developing an application in React Native. I just installed the release apk in my phone and all the `fetch()` responses are same as expected one.

But then I did changes in code. I built the release apk again. I installed the application without uninstalling the old one. Now the fetch responses are totally different.

It works fine if I reinstall it.

I don't know what is wrong in that. Is there anything like clearing caches or something needed to update the app?

Comment: It maybe some cache problems or something like that as you said that it works fine if reinstalled

Comment: @Irfanwani but we can't do that for release version.right? (Every time reinstalling)